# onActivityResult is not call in my app

Tags: android

I have two activities "A" and "B".

In my "A" activity I use startActivityForResult:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
startActivityForResult(i, 121245);
finish();
```

This is the code of my "B" activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(B.this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          

    if(requestCode == 121245) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            //make something        
    }
}
```

Why my Toast doesn't show?

Comment: what trying to do using current code?

Comment: You are handling it in the wrong activity. Write your Toast in class A since it is starting B for result.

Comment: Hey you need to read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html . You are on wrong track.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onActivityResult` will be called on the activity which is **starting the activity for result**, meaning calls the `startActivityForResult` method

What that means is if you want to be notified when the B activity finishes in A activity, you would first in A activity start the B activity like you did in your example code

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
startActivityForResult(i, 121245);
```

then when B activity finishes A activity's `onActivityResult`is called and there you can do whatever you want.

Here's a diagram if it helps you understand the flow of the application

[image: diagram]

Comment: Amazing is that 2 upvotes!!!! `startActivityForResult(i, 121245);
finish();` will Activity A be live to listen results??

Comment: Yes, but the A activity shouldn't be finish()'ed after calling startActivityForResult

Comment: Can I finish() "A" activity?

Comment: I think finishing A activity will stop it from receiving callback. Why would you want to finish it?

Comment: @PankajKumar sorry, it was a quick copy paste, didn't mean to add it there

I am glad you got it working!

Comment: All Done with in 3 mins.

Comment: Isn't internet fast, huh?

Answer (score 5):

You have a little mistake

at A class should be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 121245);
```

at B class to return:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

and handle it at A

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(B.this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          

    if(requestCode == 121245) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            //make something        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onActivityResult()
```

must be the part of your **A** activity, Your **B** activity will return some data back to **A** and then `onActivityResult()` will be called.